# Reading files directly from the memory of another computer over a network

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, filesystems, deep-learning

1. I am doing a large scale deep learning experiment involving image data of the order of around 800 GB.
2. The space available on a computational server is only 30 GB, and cannot be extended to match 800 GB.
3. At present I counter the problem by dividing my data using Python into chunks of 30 GB, and then process them by copying using openssh. Everytime I need another chunk, I delete the present chunk and then repeat the process for the next chunk. For several epochs of CNN training, this process is repeated hundreds of time.
4. Though I have not benchmarked, but I am concerned if this is a very major performance bottleneck, because CNN training itself takes weeks on a data of this scale. Repeated copying might be very costly.
5. I have never had an opportunity to face this issue so now I am thinking, if it is possible for me to read files directly from the memory of my storage server for processing.

Specifically my questions are :

- Is it possible to read files directly from memory of another system, as though the files are on the same system, without explicit scp ?
- What kind of C++ framework(s) are available for doing something like that ?
- What techniques are typically used by professional programmers in such a resource-constrained situation ?

I am not a computer science major and this is my first stint where I am faced with such performance-centric issues.Thus, I have almost no practical experience of dealing with such cases. So, a little enlightment or reference would be great.

Comment: I think you are looking to set up an [NFS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System). Once mounted, it behaves as part of a local file system - you just read from it like you would from a hard drive.

Comment: ... and if the NFS server has enough ram, you will be effectively reading from another server's ram.

Comment: I looked it up. It however asks for modifications to /etc/export file. If a user does not have administrative rights, in that case would he/she, contact the admin everytime for these modifications or is there a workaround for a normal user ?

Answer (score 3):

It may sound a little bit rude, but you need to realize that **you can't do any sort of real-world machine learning on a calculator**.

If you have a machine 10 years old or a dial-up internet connection, you can not analyze big data. The fact that your server has 30Gb of free hdd space at the time, when you can easily buy 1Tb for a price below 200$ means that something is really wrong here.

A lot of machine learning algorithms iterate through data many many times before they will converge, so any solution that requires to download / remove data many times will be significantly (impractically) slower. Even assuming a pretty fast and steady 200 Mb/s connection it will take you a couple of hours to download the whole data. Now repeat this even 100 times (NN converging after 100 iterations is mostly impossible) and you will see how bad is your situation.

This is close to my final remark - **if you want to work with big-data, upgrade your machine to handle big data**

Comment: I do not have a 10 year old machine and I do not use a dial-up connection.
The system instead of being my own system, can very well be a shared computational node. The problem I am facing is very basic and the rate at which big data is growing, quite frankly we cannot take a sigh of relief by spending a few dollars to buy hard disk. So, trying to tackle this problem under a resource-scarce situation is not very out of the league for me.  In any case, you could have written a comment instead of an answer when it was a suggestion you were trying to extend. Peace.

Comment: @UjjwalAryan even if your machine was bought yesterday, it doesn't change the fact that it is severely outdated. I would argue that no, you aren't facing a basic problem. Any resource constrained (RC) computation is hard, and RC NN is something of active research now. And in most of the cases in RC environment you sacrifice something (speed/accuracy) for this resource. I have written an answer, because I believe this is an answer. I see questions like this (**I have 128Mb ram/30Gb hdd/1Ghz proc, how can I analyse your 1Tb of data**) often on kaggle. And the answer is - update machine.

Answer (score 0):

Which costs more, the explicit cost of copying, or the implicit and hidden cost of reading data with latency?

As a data point, Google just announced a distributed version of TensorFlow.  Which can do CNN training.  (See https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html for details.)  And in that, each machine winds up processing a chunk of data at a time.  In a way that is not dissimilar to what you are already doing.

Comment: I think explicit cost of copying is more. It also involves many deletions. Every copy of data would involve creation of multiple page files and OS Kernel doing a bunch of tasks involved with storage allocation. Reading of data directly will involve latency. However, I think it can still be controlled by using memory-mapped files, if the storage server behaves like a local disk. Though I am unsure at this moment about the implementation.